# Find the connected components of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=\frac{1}{n}\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $A_n=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : y=\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $X=\{(0,0)\}\cup A_n$ $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$.
The connected components of $X-\{(0,0)\}$ are $\{A_n : n\in\Bbb{N}\}$. But what happens with $\{(0,0)\}$?

For all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ you can separate $\{(0,0)\}$ from $A_n$. But all open neighborhood of $\{(0,0)\}$ contain points of an $A_n$. Any hint?

Comment: The component containing the origin is the largest connected set containing the origin. If $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\subsetneqq A\subseteq X$, can $A$ be connected?

Comment: The definition of X is gibberish.